# Interpreting results of multinominal logistic regression

Tags: categorical-data, stata, multinomial-logit, interpretation

I have run a multinominal logistic model with my dependent categorical variable, `WINNING_PARTY`, taking the following values: gov, corp, org, indiv, univ, or in part.

I am using two independent variables called `APPELLANT_PARTY` and `RESPONDENT_PARTY` which have the same possible values: gov, corp, org, indiv, and univ.

The screenshot below shows the output of the STATA command

```
mlogit winning_party appellant_party respondent_party
```

Given that the independent variables are categorical, not binary, I am unsure how to interpret the affect of the value of `APPELLANT_PARTY` and `RESPONDENT_PARTY` on the `WINNING_PARTY`.

Comment: Stata (or you) should dummy code categorical predictors so that they are binary.

Comment: Thanks. I've done that, but one problem that arises when I include the binary variables is that the functions are not concave and do not converge...Please let me know if there is a way to enhance the model with binary variables...Thanks.

Comment: How are you entering the categorical variables? If you enter categorical variables as something else (continuous?) your estimates don't make sense. If your models don't converge, my hunch would be that you have too many empty cells. (In my experience, Stata runs into convergence problems more than other programs.)

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try to run it in python to see if STATA is the issue. The binary variables I am using are valued either '1' or '0' and no more than 5 of 668 observations should be missing. Could multicollinearity be a problem? Almost all of the 5 + binary variables are coded '0' most of the time (usually only one of the binary variables is coded '1' per observation). Thanks again.

Comment: It's not that the data are missing, it's if your have predictors, A, B, C, D, E (etc) and outcome 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, you need some values of A1, some values of A2 ... some values of E5.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I think that is not a problem in my database. I ran the model in python and it worked, but if I made small changes to the model it 'blew up'. I will update the question later today. Big thanks.